# is it possible to write php code in address bar and its gonna work?

Tags: php

Is it possible if i use in address bar this

`host.com?<?php unlink("/img/bg.jpg");?>`

or

`host.com?<?php rename("/bg.jpg","bg.png");?>`

if not then is there any way to do that?

Comment: Security-theater as a tag does not apply here.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly yes, or very close to it, *but only due to bugs and/or misconfiguration*. For CGI PHP installations there *was* recently an arbitrary remote code execution using the query string: [CVE-2012-1823](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2012-1823)

Detailed write up by *Eindbazen* who discovered it at a Nullcon CTF:
  http://eindbazen.net/2012/05/php-cgi-advisory-cve-2012-1823/

There's a [Metasploit module](http://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/http/php_cgi_arg_injection) to leverage this too.

Comment: thnx.actually i am not gonna do anything. i am php developer and studing about security and saw a video sql injection but not like others. they was injection there code from address bar. thats the reason i ask this question.

Comment: one cannot think as stupid as some wannabe php-c0derz are, sadly. btw, backdoors might work that way.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would be a huge security issue if you could send php code in the address bar and have the webpage interpret it, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, we are on http://security.stackexchange.com -- I don't think a simple 'no' really does this question justice. Obviously it is not designed behavior and shouldn't happen. That doesn't mean it can't/doesn't happen though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no -- at least probably not. Both the web server and PHP interpreter are smart enough not to pass such user-generated values through something that can execute it -- under normal circumstances. The key being 'normal circumstances' here. There could be a vulnerability in the server software that allows for this, but it likely wouldn't be as simple as your example shows.

Supposing the developer writing an application did something stupid though and enabled dynamic evaluation of PHP against an unvalidated input, then yeah, it might be possible to do what you're asking. Further, even if it were validated input, an attacker might be able to bypass it if they're smart enough. Dynamic code evaluation/execution is evil 99% of the time.